# Is there a way to use jquery map text into json from a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

First of all, I am asking this question is due to a broken API of petfinder. I am working on a rabbit rescue app (its web interface) and need some of petfinder's search results. Hopefully they fix the public API soon, but meanwhile I am using PHP to load their html content of search results and turn it into json for my front end to display.

The current method I use is to load the page into a invisible div tag and use jquery selector to map the content. But this is not efficient because it will also load up some of the original script and css files from petfinder. I would like to be able to manipulate the string directly.

Here are some of the examples:

Original code structure:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body style="background:#ffffff">
    <style type="text/css">
      ...
    </style>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" >
      <table>
        ...
          ...
            <tr class = "pfrow2">
              <td><a href="//www.petfinder.com/petdetail/30773115" class="pflink" target="_blank">
                Billie Bunny
                </a>
              </td>
              <td>
                Rabbit
              </td>
              <td>
                Dutch
              </td>
              <td>
                Adult
              </td>
              <td>
                Small
              </td>
              <td class='legacy'>
                <a href="//www.petfinder.com/petdetail/30773115" target="_blank">
                <img src="//drpem3xzef3kf.cloudfront.net/photos/pets/30773115/1/?bust=1415669533&width=130" class="img pets" border="0">
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="pfrow1">
              <td><a href="//www.petfinder.com/petdetail/30891970" class="pflink" target="_blank">
                Barnabas Bunny
                </a>
              </td>
              <td>
                Rabbit
              </td>
              <td>
                Himalayan, New Zealand
              </td>
              <td>
                Young
              </td>
              <td>
                Medium
              </td>
              <td class='legacy'>
                <a href="//www.petfinder.com/petdetail/30891970" target="_blank">
                <img src="//drpem3xzef3kf.cloudfront.net/photos/pets/30891970/3/?bust=1421966387&width=130" class="img pets" border="0">
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            ...
```

As you can see the information I really need is within `tr class = "pfrow2"` and `tr class = "pfrow1"`. I wonder if there is a way I could do a similar grab `$(".pfrow2").map(function(){})` if the class is actually within the string.

Alternatively, can I cut out the DOM before `pfrow2` and after `pfrow1`?

BTW this is my current json output (note that I change width of the image because I want to use larger thumbnails).

```
[{
  name: "Billie Bunny",
  type: "Dutch",
  age: "Adult",
  size: "Small",
  thumb: "//drpem3xzef3kf.cloudfront.net/photos/pets/30773115/1/?bust=1415669533&width=300",
  link: "//www.petfinder.com/petdetail/30773115"
},{
  name: "Barnabas Bunny",
  type: "Himalayan, New Zealand",
  age: "Young",
  size: "Medium",
  thumb: "//drpem3xzef3kf.cloudfront.net/photos/pets/30891970/3/?bust=1421966387&width=300",
  link: "//www.petfinder.com/petdetail/30891970"
}]
```

Comment: Sorry, the code above is being returned by PHP, and you want to parse out the 2 table rows, returning JSON?

Comment: @mark in short yes, except of course there will normally be more than 2 rows (like a hundred of so).

Comment: @mark and I know how to cut out the string before pfrow2 but don't know how to cut out the strings after pfrow1.

Comment: What do you want the json structure to look like?

Comment: @mark I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to make the string directly but I was able to cut the rows out for you. Assuming `data` is the result returned by your php.

```
var json = data.substring(data.indexOf('<tr class = "pfrow2">') - 21);
    json = json.substring(0,json.lastIndexOf('</td>') + 5);
    function widthChange() {
      if (json.indexOf('&width=130') != -1) {
        json = json.replace('&width=130','&width=300');
        widthChange();
      } else {
        console.log(json);
        // here you can inset json into your DOM
      }
    }
    widthChange();
```